# Method for Self Teaching

Tags: resource-request

I'm very interested in linguistics and cultures/societies, however, I cannot, at this time, go to college. I'm fairly good with teaching myself things, however, and would like to know what methods (ie. Sites, books, etc.) are good for Self educating myself on linguistics. I am seeking specifics including address / title / author and a description of why and what makes it a good resource. If this is off topic, please let me know nicely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

There is a MOOC being offered through Coursera: https://www.coursera.org/course/humanlanguage

The virtual linguistics campus has some good content and is well taught but might be difficult to navigate for a new student. It's good if you have a topic in mind: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaMpov1PPVXGcKYgwHjXB3g

The ling space gives a lot of quick high-level explanations of important lingustic phenomena--I've even found it useful in my own classes
https://www.youtube.com/user/thelingspace

If you want to drill down into grammar and x-bar theory, I'd recommend this series of calming and zen-like videos by Caroline Heycock https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNRhI4Cc_QmvBzEBJFiOUfmMR4ew9TFwO

The Study of Language by George Yule is a great introduction to linguistics, and is written in a way that's very accessible to newcomers. http://www.cambridge.org/ca/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/english-language-and-linguistics-general-interest/study-language-5th-edition?format=PB&isbn=9781107658172

All Things Linguistic is an awesome blog by Gretchen McCulloch, and has a lot of resources and advice for students in addition to delving into some interesting linguistic topics http://allthingslinguistic.com/

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly look into these, but will wait a bit longer before choosing yours as my answer, to give others a chance.

Answer (score 0):

[The Great Courses](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/) have some college-level [courses in linguistics](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/category/literature-language/linguistics.html). I haven't watched it myself, but [Understanding Linguistics: The Science of Language](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/literature-language/linguistics/understanding-linguistics-the-science-of-language.html) looks like a good starting point.

Note: the discounts are very frequent, so if there are none for the course you want, I recommend waiting a bit, or finding a discounted course set rather than buying it for the full price. You may also check if the courses you want are available on [The Great Courses Plus](https://www.thegreatcoursesplus.com/), and see which site provides a better option for you. The "Plus" version is subscription-based, and gives you access to all the courses for a limited period.

As for the books, I recommend finding a linguistics programme at a respectable university and looking at the websites of individual courses. They will usually contain the syllabus, and you'll be able to see what you can add to your reading list.